# Erro na utilização do WS da Receita Federal, (Rejeição: Usar somente o namespace padrão da NF-e)

Tags: web-service, node.js, soap, nfe

Olá! Estou tentando acessar o serviço SOAP de homologação da Receita Federal para executar a consulta de status de serviço, já fiz todas as combinações possíveis (incluindo as presentes no último [manual](http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/exibirArquivo.aspx?conteudo=URCYvjVMIzI=) publicado) na construção de *request* SOAP e dados de mensagem sem sucesso, abaixo os recursos e resultados dos testes:

WSDL utilizado para a construção do cliente SOAP (origem: https://homologacao.nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/nfestatusservico2.asmx?WSDL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Serviço destinado à consulta do status do serviço prestado pelo Portal da Secretaria de Fazenda Estadual.</wsdl:documentation>
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
      <s:element name="nfeDadosMsg">
        <s:complexType mixed="true">
          <s:sequence>
            <s:any />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Result">
        <s:complexType mixed="true">
          <s:sequence>
            <s:any />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="nfeCabecMsg" type="tns:nfeCabecMsg" />
      <s:complexType name="nfeCabecMsg">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="cUF" type="s:string" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="versaoDados" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute />
      </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12In">
    <wsdl:part name="nfeDadosMsg" element="tns:nfeDadosMsg" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12Out">
    <wsdl:part name="nfeStatusServicoNF2Result" element="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2Result" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="nfeStatusServicoNF2nfeCabecMsg">
    <wsdl:part name="nfeCabecMsg" element="tns:nfeCabecMsg" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
    <wsdl:operation name="nfeStatusServicoNF2">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Consulta Status do Serviço</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12In" />
      <wsdl:output message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2Soap12Out" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12" type="tns:NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="nfeStatusServicoNF2">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2/nfeStatusServicoNF2" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2nfeCabecMsg" part="nfeCabecMsg" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:nfeStatusServicoNF2nfeCabecMsg" part="nfeCabecMsg" use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="NfeStatusServico2">
    <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">Serviço destinado à consulta do status do serviço prestado pelo Portal da Secretaria de Fazenda Estadual.</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port name="NfeStatusServico2Soap12" binding="tns:NfeStatusServico2Soap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://homologacao.nfe.fazenda.sp.gov.br/ws/nfestatusservico2.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

SOAP *request* gerado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
                 xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
    <soap12:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
            <cUF>35</cUF>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap12:Header>
    <soap12:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <consStatServ versao="3.10">
                <cUF>35</cUF>
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
            </consStatServ>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

XML da mensagem:

```
<nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
    <consStatServ versao="3.10">
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
    </consStatServ>
</nfeDadosMsg>
```

XML de resposta do *request*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <cUF>35</cUF>
            <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeStatusServicoNF2Result xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <retConsStatServ versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <verAplic>SP_NFE_PL_008i2</verAplic>
                <cStat>587</cStat>
                <xMotivo>Rejeição: Usar somente o namespace padrão da NF-e</xMotivo>
                <cUF>35</cUF>
                <dhRecbto>0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00</dhRecbto>
            </retConsStatServ>
        </nfeStatusServicoNF2Result>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Nas tentativas de resolver o problema, inferindo que os *namespaces* adicionais no *evelope* SOAP fossem a causa, construi o *request* com os mesmos *namespaces* da resposta, alterando de:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
                 xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
```

para:

```
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" 
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

Mas não obtive sucesso. Enfim, se alguém aqui já enfrentou este problema e puder compartilhar a solução seria ótimo!

Tecnologias utilizadas:

NodeJS

node-soap (github.com/vpulim/node-soap)

Código da chamada para o WS:

```
        var url = __server_settings.nfe.wsdl[__server_settings.nfe.environments.STAGING].service_status;

        var options = {
            envelopeKey: 'soap12',
            forceSoap12Headers: true
        }

        soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {
            pfx_utils.extractPfxInfo(path.resolve(__server_settings.paths.CERTIFICATES, 'certificate.pfx'), '<password>', function (err, results, key, certificate) {
                if (err == null) {

                    client.setSecurity(new soap.ClientSSLSecurity(key, certificate));

                    var header = {
                        nfeCabecMsg: {
                            attributes: {
                                xmlns: 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2'
                            },
                            versaoDados: '3.10',
                            cUF: 35
                        }
                    };
                    client.addSoapHeader(header);

                    var data = {
                        consStatServ: {
                            attributes: {
                                versao: '3.10',
                                xmlns: 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2'
                            },
                            cUF: 35,
                            tpAmb: 2,
                            xServ: 'STATUS'
                        }
                    }

                    client.nfeStatusServicoNF2(data, function(err, result) {
                        console.log(result);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(__('Error extracting data from certificate!'));
                }
            });
        });
```

Grato!

Paulo Eduardo Ferreira Ventura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente resolvido, o XML correto:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
               xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
    <soap:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <cUF>35</cUF>
            <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <consStatServ versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <cUF>35</cUF>
                <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
            </consStatServ>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

XML **INCORRETO**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2"
                 xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/">
    <soap12:Header>
        <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
            <cUF>35</cUF>
        </nfeCabecMsg>
    </soap12:Header>
    <soap12:Body>
        <nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
            <consStatServ versao="3.10">
                <cUF>35</cUF>
                <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
            </consStatServ>
        </nfeDadosMsg>
    </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

O que fez com que a requisição falhasse foram a ordem das propriedades dispostas no cabeçalho do envelope SOAP, as ordens das propriedades área de dados da mensagem e o *namespace* da *tag* **consStatServ** que não havia sido informado. O erro apresentado me guiou a procurar o problema relacionando-o apenas aos *namespaces* **(Rejeição: Usar somente o namespace padrão da NF-e)**, e foi reclamando sobre a frustração com um colega de trabalho que fui atentado a verificar a ordem das propriedades nas áreas de dados da requisição SOAP.

Cabeçalho SOAP errôneo:

```
<soap:Header>
    <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
    </nfeCabecMsg>
</soap:Header>
```

Cabeçalho SOAP **CORRETO**:

```
<soap12:Header>
    <nfeCabecMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
        <versaoDados>3.10</versaoDados>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
    </nfeCabecMsg>
</soap12:Header>
```

Dados de mensagem errônea:

```
<nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
    <consStatServ versao="3.10">
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
    </consStatServ>
</nfeDadosMsg>
```

Dados da mensagem **CORRETA**:

```
<nfeDadosMsg xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NfeStatusServico2">
    <consStatServ versao="3.10" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
        <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
        <cUF>35</cUF>
        <xServ>STATUS</xServ>
    </consStatServ>
</nfeDadosMsg>
```

Eu poderia ter validado o XML utilizando o esquema fornecido pela SEFAZ, mas como o *request* é construído dinamicamente pela API que estou usando isso não foi possível.

**The End! E que ninguém mais no mundo sofra por posições de elementos em um XML!**

[SOAP XML Property Order is Important](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bing_ads_api/2008/03/27/soap-xml-property-order-is-important/)